# JavaScript - getElementById not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two button groups which I want to response to each other. When one button is clicked, another should be clicked to and vice versa but somehow this simple functionality doesn't work as it should, nothing happens when buttons are activated. What's the problem?

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="pol1" onclick="document.getElementById('chin2').click()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Polski</button>
            <button id="chin1" onclick="document.getElementById('pol2').click()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Chiński</button>
           </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="pol2" onclick="document.getElementById('chin1').click()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Polski</button>
            <button id="chin2" onclick="document.getElementById('pol1').click()"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Chiński</button>
           </div>

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Przetłumacz</button>
                 </div>
```

Comment: what you actually want to do ?

Comment: why don't you use multi selector like https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: this code working. but don't have alert or something to notification !

Comment: You realize that if it works, you'll get into an infinite loop of clicks, right?

Comment: There are no problems with the code above because it actually works. Demonstration on a fiddle (with the source above) where, however, the two buttons alerts popups when the clicks are fired: https://jsfiddle.net/zyta33fd/ .

Answer (score 1):

Actually your Button click is works..

but you put nested click .. and you didnt mentioned anything on that ...

so button click happens twice or sometimes but you dont know...

Here is the [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mzmmohideen/70wws6z4/4/)  have some alert for that click ...

```
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change1" onclick="document.getElementById('byBtn1').click()"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn1" value="Change" onclick="document.getElementById('byBtn').click()"/>
```